# RabbitMQ consumer + MySQL loads

Tags: mysql, performance, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm new to AMQP and RabbitMQ technology. I was used to store queues in mysql tables, but as my projects growing up, they need do change this behaviour. Install and settings RabbitMQ was completely ok. One of my projects processing a lot of xml files (billions of rows each day). So, I created dummy producer that just split XML file to elements (1....) and push these elements (thousands each xml file) to exchange with specific routing key . This is ok. I wrote one example worker, which should process these elements and save data to database. But this is the problem because I can't read more that one message at time. So, I need to load actual data from database, compare them to XML element and push new data to my table one by one. On file with 10000 rows, I need to execute about 6 queries. And this is not so good for MySQL performance. In Mysql queue based solution, I just load actual data for 1000 rows instead of one, processed these rows and marked them as processed. So, there where only few MySQL queries that loaded data for many rows. Is something like this possible in AMQP based systems like rabbit? Load 1000 of messages, process them at once and ACK them at once? Was RabbitMQ created for behaviur like this or I need to use another technology?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, your case seems to be exactly [this example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html). So simply fire up 1000 subscribers if you need that much.

Comment: Firing 1000 subscribers doesn't help, they are separated processes and I can't pass data from one subscriber to another subscriber. And with actual settings, 1000 subscribres processing messages one by one will shut mysql down.